# Can't insert into SQL Server database

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm learning Visual Basic. Now I have trouble with insert data into my table. I have tried every possible query and I still can't insert data into my table via form. Here is code:
Code from my form:

```
Private Sub UpisiButt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpisiButt.Click
        InsertData()
    End Sub
    Private Sub InsertData()
        SQL.AddParam("@sifra", TbSifra.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@naziv", TbNaziv.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@user", "Root")
        SQL.AddParam("@Skriven", 0)
        SQL.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO dbo.VrsteNalogaTable (Id, Sifra, Naziv, user, DatumUpisa, Skriven) VALUES (@sifra,@naziv,@user,GETDATE(),@Skriven);")
        MsgBox("Dodani podaci")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Class from where I load functions

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class VrsteNalogaClassNET
    Private connection As New SqlConnection("SERVER=DESKTOP-SQMPH0E\JASIMSQL;Database=VrsteNaloga;Trusted_Connection=True;User=Jasim;Pwd=1234;")
    Private DBCmd As SqlCommand
    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable
    'Query Params
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    'Query Statistics
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    'Allow connection string override
    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
        connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    End Sub
    ' Execute query sub
    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        'Reset query stats
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = 0
        Try
            connection.Open()
            ' CREATE DB Command
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, connection)
            ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            ' CLEAR PARAM
            Params.Clear()

            'EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATASET

            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'CAPTURE ERROR
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        Finally
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then connection.Close()

        End Try
    End Sub
    'ADD PARAMS
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Notice: I can Select data and display on my grid, trouble is when I try to insert via my form.

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: Have you tried to drop a breakpoint and copy them values into an identical insert statement in SSMS? That would tell you if it is the values within the insert causing the issue or not.

Comment: As per @T.S. says you really haven't told us what isn't working.  Are you getting an exception maybe, data not being inserted as expected.  On your question though, few suggestions.  Think you might working a little at cross purposes.  For an insert, it would be more expected to use  .SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery rather than the Fill method.  I would also look at how to use "Uses", SqlConnection implements IDisposable so it can make your code and error handling a lot tidier.

Comment: Further on, having a central class to consolidate your DB access as you've got here is a nice ambition, since you're just learning you might be better to keep it nice and simple until you've got the fundamentals nailed, then look at streamlining

Comment: @Hursey you've got it!!! How to use Data adapter with INSERT to load table??? No, you see, OP is confused. Data adapter can be used for INSERT but for that you need to set INSERT command. And use table as data source. And I think, even then, you still need SELECT command set. Regardless - you are correct. OP needs to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` in this case and throw away `DataAdapter` and `DataTable`. Thar is completely different technique!!

Comment: @T.S. Not sure it's completely true to simply throw away the DataSet.Fill(), Looking at the code here, that method seems perfectly valid for queries/retrieving data.  Probably just need a 2nd method for implementing ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @Hursey Not a bad argument. Look, the method name is `ExecQuery`. `cmd` method is called `ExecuteNonQuery`. So, OP probably does not know that **query** can't be `insert`. Query is `select`. This is SQL. `insert` is DML. With this logic, the solution is that OP must create another method, called `ExecDML` and use that for C_UD :-)

Comment: And depending on usages, maybe something for ExecuteScaler too

Comment: `USER` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in T-SQL, so it should be escaped as `[USER]` to use it as a column name.

Comment: There are 6 column names but only 5 values.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think, `Id` has to go. This is probably `identity`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
DBDT = New DataTable
DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
```

With this

```
RecordCount = DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

For the explanation - see the comment I left under your question

**Note:** `RecordCount` will return number of all affected records even those affected by triggers, if any exist. Store procedures record count will always be `-1`

Comment: @ghostl33t **NOTE** This answer does not cover some other issues as pointed in comments. For example - columns vs parameters count. Check the comments